# Requirejs optimiser - Create minified groupings of scripts for sections of the site

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm using the requirejs optimiser and I have a lot of JavaScript files for this webapp. I would like to create separate minified scripts which group scripts for certain sections of the site.

My question is: how do I create minified groups of scripts and how I prevent script libraries for example JQuery from being added into these module groups which already exist in the scripts.min.js core script?

```
({
    baseUrl: '../static/js',
    mainConfigFile: '../static/js/main.js',
    name: 'main',
    out: '../static/js/scripts.min.js',
    paths: {
        requireLib: 'vendor/require/require.min'
    },
    include: ['requireLib', '_core']
})
```

The current setup above adds all non nested requires plus all the scripts inside _core module and combines it to create one script that is essential for every page.

Now I need to create separate minified scripts for search, user management etc I would like each section (which contains many files) to have its own minified and concatenated script.

For example the user management pages would have these script includes:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/scripts.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/user_management.min.js"></script>
```

I have been following this tutorial to get the optimiser running: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m6VNhqKDM4E

Answer (score 1):

Check out [modules](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js#L334) in the requirejs example build

You can set a common build file that includes all shared scripts

And then you can have separate modules for each other page

Use `include[]` and `exclude[]` to include modules in the built files

Answer (score 0):

Since you're separating your compiled scripts into separate files, I'm guessing you need `scripts.min.js` to act as a shared set of components across multiple pages.

If so, the problem you're describing is solved in the [example-multipage](https://github.com/requirejs/example-multipage) and [example-multipage-shim](https://github.com/requirejs/example-multipage-shim) repositories. They are by the RequireJS creator and are pretty straightforward.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17035609/723007) and its accepted answer are also great references to the options available for a multipage config with RequireJS.